# How to handle strings with a block ( awk )

Tags: awk

Each block starts with 'COL ID' in an input data. 
I need to print 'COL ID' and JOB_subid if there is. As you can see in input data, 'COLID=2' has a job_subid(1 / left of table name) but 'COLID=3' or 'COLID=4' doesn't have. 
For COLID=3/4, I want to print 'no_data' as it doesn't have any job_subid.
How can I handle this data?

## AWK

```
/COL ID/        {JOBID=$4;}

/^[0-9]/ {
    JOB_SUBID=$1;
    printf "%s#%s",JOBID,JOB_SUBID;
    printf "\n";
} 

END {

if (JOB_SUBID="") then
  JOB_SUBID="no_data";
  printf "%s#%s",JOBID,JOB_SUBID;
  printf "\n";
end if;

}
```

## input data

```
COL ID    : 2
PID       : 26788


ID     TABLE                         
------ ------------------------------
1      "SCOTT"."PRINCE01"            


COL ID    : 3
PID       : 26788


COL ID    : 4
PID       : 26788
```

## Incorrect result

```
2#1
4#no_data
```

## Required result

```
2#1
3#no_data
4#no_data
```

Comment: `if () then ... end if`? Not sure what language you're thinking of but you can learn awk from the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. Don't use all upper case variable name to avoid clashing with builtin variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply do this by

```
$ awk -v RS='COL ID' 'NR>1{print $2"#"($10==""?"no data":$10)}' file
2#1
3#no data
4#no data
```

Brief explanation,

- Set the record separator as `COL ID`
- `NR>1`: Omit the first record
- Check if `$10` subid existed, print "no data" if not.

Comment: You should mention that's gawk-specific due to the multi-char RS.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the same style as listed then just add this statement.

`/^[^0-9]/ {JOB_SUBID = ""}`
and get rid of the `END` block

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '/COL ID/{ 
        if(colid) { sid=(subid)? subid:"no_data"; print colid"#"sid; subid="" } colid=$4 
     }
     /^[0-9]+/{ subid=$1 }END{ if(colid) print colid"#"sid }' inputfile
```

The output:

```
2#1
3#no_data
4#no_data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/COL ID/ { prt(); jobId = $NF }
/^[0-9]/ { subId = $1 }
END { prt() }
function prt() { if (NR>1) print jobId "#" subId; subId="no_data" }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2#1
3#no_data
4#no_data
```